# Modifying coordinate values of MultiPolygon using GeoTools?

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I can already get the vertex coordinates of the polygon, but I want to modify the coordinates and write it back to the source file.
This is part of the code I read the coordinates.

```
try{
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
          SimpleFeature sf = iter.next();
          Collection<Property> property =((ComplexAttribute)sf).getProperties();
          Iterator<Property> iterP = property.iterator();
          while (iterP.hasNext()) {
              Property pro = iterP.next();
              if (pro.getValue() instanceof MultiPolygon) {
                  gisObjectList.add((T) new GisMultiPolygon ((MultiPolygon)pro.getValue(), (SimpleFeature) sf));
                   Geometry gc = (MultiPolygon) pro.getValue();
                  Coordinate[] points = gc.getCoordinates();
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

---

I created a new shapefile from the original shapefile, but there was a runtime error.
error is org.geotools.data.directory.DirectoryDataStore cannot be cast to org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.

```
public static void transShape(File shpFile, File shpFile2) {
    try {
        //源shape文件
        ShapefileDataStore shapeDS = (ShapefileDataStore) new ShapefileDataStoreFactory().createDataStore(shpFile.toURI().toURL());
        //创建目标shape文件对象
        Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
        FileDataStoreFactorySpi factory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();
        params.put(ShapefileDataStoreFactory.URLP.key, shpFile2.toURI().toURL());
        ShapefileDataStore ds = (ShapefileDataStore) factory.createNewDataStore(params);
        // 设置属性
        SimpleFeatureSource fs = shapeDS.getFeatureSource(shapeDS.getTypeNames()[0]);
        //下面这行还有其他写法，根据源shape文件的simpleFeatureType可以不用retype，而直接用fs.getSchema设置
        ds.createSchema(SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.retype(fs.getSchema(), DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84));
        //设置writer
        FeatureWriter<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> writer = ds.getFeatureWriter(ds.getTypeNames()[0], Transaction.AUTO_COMMIT);
        //写记录
        SimpleFeatureIterator it = fs.getFeatures().features();
        try {
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature f = it.next();
                SimpleFeature fNew = writer.next();
                fNew.setAttributes(f.getAttributes());
                writer.write();
            }
        } finally {
            it.close();
        }
        writer.close();
        ds.dispose();
        shapeDS.dispose();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a `GeometryFactory`:

```
GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
```

And then you need to break each `MultiPolygon` up into it's `Polygon`s and then for each `Polygon` deal with the exterior boundary and any holes in turn and then convert those back to a list of `Polygon`s and finally build a new `MultiPolygon`.

```
               MultiPolygon gc = (MultiPolygon) pro.getValue();
               ArrayList<Polygon> polygons = new ArrayList<>();
               for(int i=0;i<gc.getNumGeometries();i++) {
                 Polygon p=(Polygon) gc.getGeometryN(i); 
                 Coordinate[] points = p.getExteriorRing().getCoordinates();
                 for (Coordinate c: points) {
                   // do whatever you want to the coords here
                   c.x += 10;
                   c.y += 10;
                 }
                 LinearRing shell = gf.createLinearRing(points);
                 LinearRing[] holes = new LinearRing[p.getNumInteriorRing()];
                 if(p.getNumInteriorRing()>0) {
                   for(int k=0;k<p.getNumInteriorRing();k++) {
                     Coordinate[] ring = p.getInteriorRingN(k).getCoordinates();
                     for (Coordinate c: points) {
                       // do whatever you want to the coords here
                       c.x += 10;
                       c.y += 10;
                     }
                     holes[k] = gf.createLinearRing(ring);
                   }
                 }
                 Polygon poly = gf.createPolygon(shell,holes);
                 polygons.add(poly);
               }
              MultiPolygon nMP = gf.createMultiPolygon(polygons.toArray(new Polygon[] {}));
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. But I want to make a coordinate replacement on the original file, not a new one

Comment: then set the new multipolygon as the features default geom, but you will still need to write the features to disk

Comment: I have to create a new one and cannot modify it on the original file.

Comment: A GeoTools FeatureCollection is an in memory representation of the file's contents, you can write it back over the original file if you are brave. Maybe you need to ask a new question that explains your broader problem

Comment: How can I write back the original file?

Comment: Or, I want to generate a new file, only change the coordinate data, other attribute information is unchanged, what should I do?

Comment: this is a new question

Comment: Is there a similar code for reference?